# vaadin: use javascript library like jspdf to create pdf of the html content

Tags: javascript, java, html, pdf, vaadin

I am working with Vaadin 7 and i have created some charts and i would like to create/download a pdf of the charts of the html content. i found out the javascript library 'jspdf' can do what i want, but i don't understand how to implement that library and how i can use it in vaadin.

A simple javascript code can be executed with this line of code:

```
Page.getCurrent().getJavascript().execute("alert('Hello World')");
```

further than that i don't know what to do.

Or maybe there is another better/simpler way to create pdf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vaadin you have two ways to create PDF:

1. Generate the PDF serverside, this way you have full controll over the resulting PDF. I won't explain how to do it here.
2. Use (for example) the jspdf lib which can create a PDF from your html content. Results may be different, depending on webbrowser etc.

To integrate any kind of JS libraries in vaadin, you can use this approach:

```
@JavaScript({ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js", "bootstrap.js", "bootstrap_connector.js" })
public class JavascriptTooltipExtension extends AbstractJavaScriptExtension {

    public void extend(Link link) {

        Resource resource = link.getResource();

        String display = resource instanceof ExternalResource ? ((ExternalResource) resource).getURL().toString() : "???";

        getState().setDisplay(display);

        super.extend(link);

        attachTooltip();
    }

    protected void attachTooltip(Object... commandAndArguments) {

        invokeCallback("attach", commandAndArguments);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends ClientConnector> getSupportedParentType() {

        return Link.class;
    }

    @Override
    public BootstrapTooltipState getState() {

        return (BootstrapTooltipState) super.getState();
    }
}
```

[Full JS integration example](https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-html-and-0)

Comment: thankyou for you answer. i will try  to do this way.